# Cannot get valid Xpath expression in grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xpath

i am trying to do selenium automation for a web page but XPath is not working for elements in `grid\spans\telerik` controls. I have used all possible scenarios to get the element's xpath.
I want to click on the highlighted area 'Reports'. Please guide me.

[image: imgur mirror]

So far I have tried:

```
//*[@id="SidebarMenu_ulOverallMenu"]/li[13]/a

/html/body/form/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div/ul/li[13]/a
```

Answer (score 0):

install firebug and firepath plugin in firefox.
You can view the xpath by using them.
Just Try By.linkText("REPORTS")

Comment: used already, no luck
I have got /html/body/form/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div/ul/li[13]/a this from firebug but its not working, the error appears no such element

Answer (score 0):

This happened many times. You made a small mistake. May be that div is not shown on the screen. So try this

```
driver.findElement(By.id("Sidebar")).click();
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.id("SidebarMenu_pnlOverAll")).click();
```

Then

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("[@id="SidebarMenu_ulOverallMenu"]/li[13]/a")).click();
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div/ul/li[13]/a")).click();
```

Comment: Try to change selenium jar version.